# Get layers and layer metadata by geoserver Restful interface

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

We are going to access geoserver by RESTful interface, now we meet some problems:

1 List all layers by data store

When using Web administration interface , Geoserver will list all layers(with status of published or not) for a certain data store:
[image]

Now how can we get the list by RESTful interface ?

2 Load the feature type metadata

Geoserver will list all the fields when create/edit a layer:

[image]

How to load the information by RESTful interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 I don't think it is possible to get the **unpublished** layers list via the REST interface.

For 2 it is available in the featuretypes endpoint - `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/states_shapefile/featuretypes.xml` under `<attributes>`

Comment: For 2, the interface you providered works only if the layer has been published. While the information like bbox,srs,attributes are required during the publishing job.

Comment: yes, that is how those fields are filled in - the user must supply this information. This may be an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - may be you could describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not XY problem, we are building a tool for user to publish OGC service without access geoserver directly. I though geoserver may serve the geo-related information like bbox, fileds since it can connect to the data store, and in fact it display these information when we use the geoserve web ui, but seems like it does not expose it by the restful api. So I may have to read the information by myself.